# show rows after removed using jquery and dropdown select

Tags: jquery, html

I created a filter to remove rows from a table according to comparison to selected value. The problem is I need to show the removed rows after user chooses a different value but I cant figure out how.
This is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $('select[name=select1]').val()) {
                $(this).parent("tr:first").remove();                    }
        });
});
```

and this is the dropdown:

```
<select name="select1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>user name</option>
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['user_name'];?>">
            <?php echo $line['user_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Is there a way I can return the removed rows to the table after `select1` changes?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to 'remove' the rows so much as 'hide' them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the css on the TR to:

```
display: none;
```

instead of removing it? Then you can add it back in by changing it to:

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the matched rows, why not just hide them and then show all rows again whenever the dropdown value is changed?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("td").each(function(index, paragraph) {
            $td = $(paragraph);
            if ($td.html() === $('select[name=select1]').val()) {
                //hide the matched row rather than remove it
                $(this).parent("tr:first").hide();
            }
    });
    $('select[name="select1"]').on('change', function() {
        $("tr").show();
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/5wo9748y/)**